# CSS - Vertical timeline, connected to dots

Tags: html, css

This is my timeline code this far, I would like to end the last timeline-post element in a yellow line and then to the last blue dot.

I have tried to add this class **.timeline:last-child::after** but this does obliviously not work!

```css
.iconspace {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #25b5f1;
  z-index: 7;
}

.iconspace i {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 49.8%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: RED;
  z-index: -5;
}

.timeline-post {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.timeline:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 49.8%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: YELLOW;
  z-index: -5;
}

.timeline:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #25b5f1;
    margin-top: 50px;
 left: 49.8%;
    border-radius: 50%; 
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="entry-title" style="text-align: center;">EDUCATION</h3><span class="border"></span>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="iconspace"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 1
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 2
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DanieleFois you need to read the question first ... the title contain **vertical** and **dots** but it has nothing to do with the one you mentionned

Comment: ok, I retracted the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `last-child` to `timeline-post` and not `timeline`. You need also to set negative value in bottom instead of using `height:100%` or your line will take the same height of the timeline-post and will never reach the blue dot.

Also never forget to add `position:relative` to element when using `position:absolute` with its pseudo-element or any child element.

```css
.iconspace {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #25b5f1;
  z-index: 7;
}

.iconspace i {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 49.8%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: RED;
  z-index: -5;
}

.timeline-post {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.timeline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #25b5f1;
  margin-top: 50px;
  left: 49.8%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeline .timeline-post {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-post:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 49.8%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: YELLOW;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="entry-title" style="text-align: center;">EDUCATION</h3><span class="border"></span>
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="iconspace"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i></div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 1
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 2
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-post">
    Test 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fjott you're welcome :) by the way if you still need help with the same code you can consider adding some comments here and i will be glad to help you ;) this will avoid you creating another question with the same code.

Comment: Well, actually I got another question you probably can help me with. 
When stacking two timelines, the bottom timeline title will overlap the 

.timeline .timeline-post:last-child::after 

see https://jsfiddle.net/cb3ras3c/1/

Comment: @Fjott you probably need to add some margin, so you may add this `h3 {
  margin-top:80px;
}`

Comment: I used @media screen and (max-width: 768px) { h3.timeline-main-title { margin-top:80px !important; }} You seems like a really skilled and helpful person, thanks a lot :)